# Reduce frequency of emulated do..while loops in Python

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x

I realised that I am coding a lot of repeated codes which revolves around an emulated do..while loop to verify user input.

Is there a way to reduce the frequency of such repeated codes?

For example:

```
validity = False
while validity == False:        
    choice = input('Enter 1 --> , 2 --> , 3 --> ....')
    if choice == '1':
        validity = True
        stuff1()
    if choice == '2':
        validity = True
        stuff2()
    if choice == '3':
        validity = True
        stuff3()
    else:
        print('Invalid Input.')
```

Comment: You can use a dictionary, if choice in dictionary stuff, else . . .

Comment: That code won't work because `choice` is a string but you're comparing it to integers. BTW, it's more Pythonic to do `while not validity:`.

Comment: A more Pythonic variable name would also be `valid` or `is_valid`, not `validity`. Reads much more naturally.

Comment: Is it the same `stuff` for each choice?  If so, why bother with the choice at all?

Comment: @PM2Ring: ah you're right, I missed out on that. Thanks.

Comment: @Neapolitan: No, it is supposed to be different. Will edit to highlight the differences.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `set`:

```
for choice in {1, 2, 3}:
    validity = True
    stuff()
```

Or a `tuple`:

```
for choice in (1, 2, 3):
    validity = True
    stuff()
```

Also rather than doing:

```
while validity == False:
```

do falsey check:

```
while not validity:
```

Comment: Are there any performance differences between `while not` and `== False`  besides semantics ?

Comment: I edited my question to make it clearer. Each option is supposed to different stuff(), my bad.

Comment: @iridescent: Yes, the 2nd form is a tiny bit more efficient, but more importantly, [PEP008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) says: "Don't compare boolean values to True or False using =="

Answer (score 1):

You can also remove `validity` and use `break` statement:

```
while True:
    choice = input('Enter 1 --> , 2 --> , 3 --> ....')
    if choice in (1, 2, 3):
        stuff()
        break
    else:
        print('Invalid Input.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean:

```
validity = False
while validity == False:        
    choice = input('Enter 1 --> , 2 --> , 3 --> ....')
    if choice == '1':
        validity = True
        stuff1()
    if choice == '2':
        validity = True
        stuff2()
    if choice == '3':
        validity = True
        stuff3()
    else:
        print('Invalid Input.')
```

then you can do:

```
actions = { '1': stuff1, '2': stuff2, '3': stuff3 }
invalid = lambda: print('Invalid Input.')
while True:
    choice = input('Enter 1 --> , 2 --> , 3 --> ....')
    action = actions.get(choice, invalid)
    action()
    if action is not invalid:
        break
```

You can put it into a reusable function:

```
def act(actions):
    while True:
        val = input('Enter 1 --> %d: '%len(actions))
        try:
            choice = int(val)-1
        except ValueError:
            choice = -1
        if not 0 <= choice < len(actions): 
            print('Invalid Input.')
        else:
            break
    actions[choice]()
```

So that you only need:

```
act([stuff1, stuff2, stuff3])
```

For example:

```
>>> act([lambda: print("chose 1"), lambda: print("chose 2"), lambda: print("chose 3")])
Enter 1 --> 3: 4
Invalid Input.
Enter 1 --> 3: 3
chose 3
```

Edit: updated to reflect use of python3 `input()`, which returns strings, and to show it works

Comment: The question has been updated: `choice` is being tested against strings, not integers.